# JMeter CompoundVariable.execute method is replacing + character with empty space

Tags: image, jmeter, url-encoding

I'm trying to substitute a value into a JSON request body using a JMeter variable and ${value_here} notation.  The value is a base64 encoded image, which includes "+" characters.

When I call `CompoundVariable.execute`, the request body contains the value in the JMeter variable, but all "+" characters have been replaced with empty strings resulting in a malformed image.

Is there some workaround for this, or do I need to work around it in code? Simplified example before, since I am sure none of you want the wall of text that would be my encoded image.

String stored in variable (truncated for brevity):

```
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
```

Variable in templated request is ${Document_Image_Front} though I'm sure that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [__urlencode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function to encode space to `+` back

> ${__urldecode(Word "school" is "école" in french)}
>   returns Word+%22school%22+is+%22%C3%A9cole%22+in+french.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. I should have thought of that

Comment: @SuperKarateDeathMonkey you can accept the answer if it helped